# Class implements Interface that extends another Interface

Tags: java, class, interface, extends, implements

I want to implement an interface in my class that extends from another interface, but I get the follow error:

> Class1 is not abstract and does not override abstract method method2(param1,param2) in Interface2

```
public class Class1 implements Interface1 {       
    public Class1() {
        //some init
    }

    @Override
    public Object method1(Object param1) {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    public void method2(Object param1, Object param2) {
        //some code
    }         
}

public interface Interface1 extends Interface2 {       
     //some specific code
}

public interface Interface2 {
    public Object method1(Object param1);
    public void method2(Object param1, Object param2);
}
```

Why doesn't it work and what do I have to do, to make it work?

Comment: You didn' t override method2 correctly, since the interface signature doesn't return anything, and your implementation returns _Object_.

Comment: Sorry was a mistake, I have corrected it !

Comment: insert the types of param1 and param2... If you override the methods with the correct params this example will compile just fine.

Comment: The "example code" you provided does not reproduce the error you describe in your post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**provide the type for the parameters param1 and param2**
try this

```
  public class Class1 implements Interface1 {       
    public Class1() {
        //some init
    }

    @Override
    public Object method1(String param1) {
        //some code
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void method2(String param1,String param2) {
        //some code
    }         
}


 interface Interface1 extends Interface2 {       
     //some specific code
}


 interface Interface2 {
    public Object method1(String param1);
    public void method2(String param1,String param2);
}
```

Comment: ah... Object is just an example in this code snipped... i don't use it really in my code, but thanks...

Comment: My mistake was the follow:  In interface2 i used an enum in the method params and ..i defined it in interface2....